# How to resolve [object Promise] issue in visual studio code extension.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Tried to get current project folder path in VS code extension.js but I am getting [object Promise] error. How to resolve this issue? Anybody can resolve this issue?

extension.js:

```
const getCurrentlyopenedprojectpath = async() => {

  const editor = window.activeTextEditor;
  if (!editor || !workspace.workspaceFolders || workspace.workspaceFolders.length < 2) {
    return null;
  }
  let text;
  const resource = editor.document.uri;
  if (resource.scheme === 'file') {
    const folder = workspace.getWorkspaceFolder(resource);
    if (!folder) {
      text = `$(alert) <outside workspace> → ${basename(resource.fsPath)}`;
    } else {
      text = `$(file-submodule) ${basename(folder.uri.fsPath)} (${folder.index + 1} of ${workspace.workspaceFolders.length}) → $(file-code) ${basename(resource.fsPath)}`;

    }
  }
  return {
    text
  };
}


console.log(getCurrentlyopenedprojectpath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to await your call. Async functions return promises. You can then either use a then to get the data when it resolves, or you can use await (if the code is within an async function).

Since you are using the call in a global scope, you need to use `then()` to catch the resolved data.

```
getCurrentlyopenedprojectpath().then(result => {
  console.log(result.text)
})
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? How isn't it working?

Comment: Nothing is priniting

Comment: Getting result is null

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any async requests in your code, so just remove async from you function.